# How do I determine if my laptop USB port is permanently broken?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, hardware-failure

I have a Compaq 620 laptop that is almost 10 years old

It has an Intel Celeron processor running Windows 7 Ultimate edition

It's battery does not hold any charge and booting the computer with the battery attached causes it to hang at the Compaq logo screen (before booting windows), so I have been using it with the battery removed and powered directly through the charger power supply

About a week ago the laptop suddenly stopped detecting devices connected to any of it's USB ports (it has 3 built in ports)

The built in keyboard and touch pad work, but connecting any USB device (USB drives, keyboard, mouse, etc) only causes the "Device not recognised" notification balloon to pop up. I also noticed that the wifi has stopped working (pressing the wifi button on the keyboard was supposed to turn the wifi radio on, and change the wifi indicator LED from yellow to blue. The LED colour changes, but it does not show any wifi detected in Windows. The wifi button was also supposed to turn on the bluetooth radio, which does not turn on either). I am suspecting the wifi/bluetooth radio is internally connected to the motherboard through USB, which has broken down if my hunch is correct

It has an SDcard slot which I can use to boot into puppy linux installed on the SDcard, but the wifi is not working in puppy linux either, which makes me think that this is a hardware problem

**What can I do to determine if this is absolutely a hardware problem, or if there is still a way I can somehow fix it through software?** I have tried the basic stuff (rebooting, trying different USB devices, rapidly plugging USB drives in/out, removing unrecognised USB device from device manager and reinstalling the driver, etc) and nothing is working. I am pretty sure that unless I can fix it myself, it is not worth getting this laptop fixed at a shop, as it already more than 10 years old.

I just want to make sure I have tried everything possible with this laptop, before bracing myself to have to pay for a new latop

PS: the down arrow key and a few other keys on the built-in keyboard are broken as well (a completely separate problem), so unless I can get it to detect at least a USB keyboard, I may not be able to try every BIOS trick

Comment: Your actions already have confirmed it is a hardware problem.

Comment: Reinstall windows 7 clean to determine if it is a hardware issue.

Comment: @ramhound im not convinced - the balloon popping up saying "device not recognised" implies a software issue.

Comment: What happens if you insert a USB disk when booted in Linux?

Comment: @davidgo - My conclusion was based on all the other issues in summation.